# How to deal with char array which '\0' is inserted into?

Tags: c++, c++11

When I try to copy a struct into a char array buffer using memcpy function, '\0' is inserted into the char array. I pass the buffer pointer to a function. the content before the first '\0' is past, but the rest is lost. How can I solve this problem? I would appreciate it if you help me.

here is the code, although the the struct Mystruct and the function display() is not designed reasonably。

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <stdio.h>

struct MyStruct
{
    char c;
    int order;
    char ch;
    MyStruct(char c = 'b', int order = 0, char ch = 'a'):order(order), ch(ch), c(c)
    {};
};

void display(char* str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyStruct *mystruct = new MyStruct;
//    char* test = new char[50];
    char test[50];
    memset(test, 0, 50);

    memcpy(test, mystruct, sizeof(MyStruct));

    display(test);


    return a.exec();
}
```

I want to send struct like 'Mystruct' through socket and the function send(char*) requires a char* pointer pointing to a buffer. The '\0' is inserted into the char array when the int order is copied into the test[50].

We use QTcpSocket::write(char* ) of QT instead of APIs offered by Linux or Windows. And my teammate offer me an interface function send(char *).I need pass the buffer pointed to by the char* pointer.

I simplized my question with the code showed and apologize for my confusing expression.And any good way to send the struct through socket?

Comment: If the data you're copying can contain null bytes and you don't want that, you'll have to clean up the data.  How you do that depends on what you want.  Search for nulls and change them to spaces?  Skip over nulls while you're copying?  Insert "(null)" when you come across a null byte?  Throw an error if the data includes null bytes?  You need to decide what should happen.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to accomplish it by taking a `struct` with: 1) a single `char`, 2) a single `int`, and 3) a second `char` value, and then taking this entire struct and interpreting it as a single character stirng? What are your expected results from this sequence of events? Why are you copying the `struct` into a single `char` buffer, and attempting to print it as if it was an ordinary null-terminated string?

Comment: String functions rely on the `'\0'` to mark the end of the string.  You need to avoid all functions that make that assumption.

Comment: Are there any good way to send the struct through socket?

Comment: What networking library do you use that doesn't take the size of the data together with the pointer to the data? If e.g. you are talking about [this `send`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/send.html), note how it takes the length together with the pointer, and doesn't rely on nul termination.

Comment: The data after '\0' is lost after the pointer is passed to a function which contains a 'send()' function rather than when the pointer is passed to the function 'send()'.

Comment: Since you never showed the code that you call between the `memcpy` and the `send` there's no way for anyone to help you.  Just avoid all string functions, as I said before.  And note that `printf` with `%s` is a string function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-string function works with nul-terminating string.

if you want to handle `char*` with nul non terminal string, you need size (or other sentinel).

```
MyStruct mystruct;

std::string buffer {(char*) &mystruct, sizeof (MyStruct)};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5758e3ab88fa1339)

Notice that that way of serializing has lot of pitfall:

- padding (you might see random value between `c` and `order` and also after `ch` (those `0` ARE random)).
- endianess issue.
- ...

Comment: thank u for ur answer. BTW, I find Qbytearray a good tool as well as std::string.